# Get the target Java method of a request in JAX-RS for authorization with Picketlink

Tags: java, jax-rs, picketlink

I have a custom implementation of the Picketlink [`PathAuthorizer`](http://docs.jboss.org/picketlink/2/2.7.1.Final/api/org/picketlink/http/authorization/class-use/PathAuthorizer.html) interface that checks if a URL is allowed for the user.

```
public class BssPathAuthorizer implements PathAuthorizer {

    @Inject
    Identity identity;

    @Override
    public boolean authorize(PathConfiguration pathConfiguration, 
                             HttpServletRequest request, 
                             HttpServletResponse response) {

        if (identity != null){

            LOG.log(Level.FINE, "Identity loggato: {0}", identity.isLoggedIn());
            String uri = request.getRequestURI();
            String contextpath = request.getContextPath();
            LOG.log(Level.FINE, "URI: {0}, context path: {1}", 
                new Object[]{uri, contextpath});

            Method m = findMethod(uri);
            ...
        }
```

After I get the method by `findMethod()`, I'll check some annotations and then return `true` if the user has permission.

- Is there a simple way to retrieve the Java method from the requested URL (for example: `.../user/edit`)?
- What is the class method that implement it (for example `UserManager.edit()`)?

Comment: I use Wildfly 9.0.2.Final with RestEASY 3.0.10.Final

Comment: Let me know if my solution works for you.

Answer (score 3):

The information you need from JAX-RS is available in the [`ResourceInfo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ResourceInfo.html) interface.

See  below how to make this information available in your Picketlink [`PathAuthorizer`](http://docs.jboss.org/picketlink/2/2.7.1.Final/api/org/picketlink/http/authorization/class-use/PathAuthorizer.html) implementation.

### Defining a class to store the data you need

Define a class annotated with [`@RequestScoped`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/context/RequestScoped.html) which will store the target class and method:

```
@RequestScoped
public class RequestTarget {

    private Class<?> targetClass;
    private Method targetMethod;

    // Default constructor, getters and setters ommited
}
```

Ensure you are using the [`@RequestScoped`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/context/RequestScoped.html) annotation from the [`javax.enterprise.context`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/context/package-summary.html) package.

### Creating a request filter

Create a [`ContainerRequestFilter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestFilter.html) to populate the `RequestTarget`:

```java
@Provider
@Priority(1)
public class RequestTargetPopulator implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Context
    private ResourceInfo resourceInfo;

    @Inject
    private RequestTarget target;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        target.setTargetClass(resourceInfo.getResourceClass());
        target.setTargetMethod(resourceInfo.getResourceMethod());
    }
}
```

The [`@Priority`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/annotation/Priority.html) annotation with the value `1` ensures this filter will be executed before other filters.

### Performing the injection

And then you can finally perform the injection of the `RequestTarget` using [`@Inject`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/inject/Inject.html):

```java
public class CustomPathAuthorizer implements PathAuthorizer {

    @Inject
    private RequestTarget target;

    @Override
    public boolean authorize(PathConfiguration pathConfiguration, 
                             HttpServletRequest request, 
                             HttpServletResponse response) {

        Class<?> targetClass = target.getTargetClass();
        Method targetMethod = target.getTargetMethod();

        ...
    }
}
```